# How can I reload view controllers from the appDelegate each time I push one on the stack?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

Currently my application has a single navigation screen that allows the user to select other views.  When clicked the navController simply does a push of the specific view controller in question.  This works great if I never come back to the same view again expecting it to be reloaded.

In the code below I push a view controller when requested.

```
- (void)optionClicked:(NSString *)optionName
{
  if ([@"First" isEqualToString:optionName]) {
    [navController pushViewController:firstController animated:YES];
  } else if ([@"Next" isEqualToString:optionName]) {
    [navController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
  }
}
```

When done with a view I simply pop it from the stack.  But the next time a user selects this same option from the menu it's not loaded "clean" and this is where my question comes in.  How can I load a view controller fresh each time it's pushed on the stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reinitialize the viewcontroller.

```
  if ([@"First" isEqualToString:optionName]) {
    if (firstController) 
    { [firstController release]; } // assuming you've got a retain on it.
    firstController = [[MyViewControllerSubclass alloc] init];
    [navController pushViewController:firstController animated:YES];
  }
```

In this situation I would suggest using a property with retain on it. `@property (nonatomic, retain) MyViewControllerSubclass *firstController;`

that way you can use `self.firstController = [[[MyViewControllerSubclass alloc] init] autorelease];` and the memory management is mostly done for you. (Although you still have to release in dealloc.)

Comment: After I added a property (nonatomic, retain) like you mentioned - should I put self. in front of firstController throughout? or just when I init it as you showed?

Comment: always use self infront if you are accessing properties. Because if you use something like `@synthesize firstController = _firstController` then the backing ivar for the property will be _firstController not firstController; This would in turn mean that firstController without self would be an invalid reference.

Comment: I'm also storing values on the app delegate itself and each view controller will ask the appDel for this information before making an action -do I need to hookup the relationship again in code after the release / init work?

Comment: btw this all makes sense if you know what the auto generated accessor code for retained properties is. see http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/7295-getters-setters-properties-newbie.html

Comment: Yes, you'll have to "rehookup". Generally speaking you shouldn't "get" values from the app delegate though they should be "pushed" to the view controllers. This is normally done by creating properties on the view controllers and then setting them from the app delegate

Comment: Ahh ok - in the short term how can I rehookup the app Delegate until I get a chance to refactor and push these down to each view Controller instead? Just a simple self.firstController setAppDelegate:self or ?

Comment: A quick and dirty solution that you can use is to put this in your view controllers. `WhatEverYourAppDelegatesClassNameIs *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];` You'll then be able to reference your app delegate with this variable. Just remember, if you want to call any methods on your delegate you'll have to import the header file into your view controller to get rid of compiler warnings.

Comment: That's how I started - glad to know that it's not a good idea (I'll put in the time to refactor this later in the week) Thanks a ton for the help!

Comment: No worries :-) t'was a pleasure.

Comment: Just as a quick note. "This is normally done by creating properties on the view controllers and then setting them from the app delegate." should probably be "This is normally done by creating properties on the view controllers and then setting them from the object that owns them".